# Apache on Ubuntu 12.04: How to find what causes folder to appear under /var/www

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

I noticed that a folder with the name of a website I removed keeps appearing under `/var/www`. I checked and it is created by `www-data`. I suspect that it's something malicious.

How can I find out what causes this?

Comment: What is the permission of this folder `ls -la /var/www`?

Comment: There are numerous apache functions which create folders on the spot, it is probably not malicious thing, but a configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that Apache itself would do to create a folder within /var/www. You might have some other software doing it--maybe a configuration panel.

You're right to be suspicious, but you should spend just a little time ruling out something else legit. Apache's not it, though.

Answer (score -2):

Obviously you want the exact process name that causes it. I would suggest something like auditd to monitor the directory in question, and pinpoint the culprit. You can find a lot of tutorials on the web regarding how to set it up and use, so I will not repost it here. If you run into troubles, or do find what causes it, post a comment.